# After Insert and Update Trigger on the same table

Tags: mysql, database-design, trigger, update, mysql-workbench

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `userlogtype` (
  `UserLogTypeID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserLogType` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertDateTime` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `UpdateUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdateDateTime` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserLogTypeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

and I would like to create 2x triggers: one after insert and one after update.

1. After Insert I would like to update the new row: InsertUser + InsertDateTime
   fields
2. After Update I would like to update the new row: UpdateUser + UpdateDateTime
   fields

I tried this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `userlogtype_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `userlogtype` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE userlogtype
    SET InsertUser = CASE WHEN InsertUser IS NULL OR InsertUser='' OR InsertUser=' ' THEN CURRENT_USER ELSE InsertUser END,
    InsertDateTime = CASE WHEN InsertDateTime IS NULL OR InsertDateTime='0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR InsertDateTime=0  THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ELSE InsertDateTime END
    WHERE UserLogTypeID=NEW.UserLogTypeID ; 
END
```

I can save the trigger without an error in MySQL Workbench, but when I test an insert (inserting just a value for UserLogType), it gives the following error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
> the database. Executing: INSERT INTO `artistabookingdb`.`userlogtype`
> (`UserLogType`) VALUES ('erty');
>
> ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'userlogtype' in stored
> function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
> this stored function/trigger. SQL Statement: INSERT INTO
> `artistabookingdb`.`userlogtype` (`UserLogType`) VALUES ('erty')

It's a bit strange that the default values not appear when I try to insert a value to the UserLogType field:
[image]

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory. You should be using `BEFORE` triggers, or, rather, a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, since you can simply use `DEFAULT` or `GENERATED` values upon insert.

Comment: @mustaccio I have more experience in MS SQL and there I could use the AFTER keyword. At first I thought my datetime field was the problem, because I got errors from that one too at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Alter the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `userlogtype` (
  `UserLogTypeID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserLogType` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertDateTime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UpdateUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdateDateTime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserLogTypeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Now the values in `InsertDateTime` and `UpdateDateTime` will be set automatically.

2. Create BEFORE (not AFTER !) triggers which will assign current user into according column if the value is not specified in the query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_bi_userlogtype` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `userlogtype` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.InsertUser = COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(NEW.InsertUser), ''), CURRENT_USER);

CREATE TRIGGER `tr_bu_userlogtype` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `userlogtype` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.UpdateUser = COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(NEW.UpdateUser), ''), CURRENT_USER);
```

TRIM() removes space chars. NULLIF() compares trimmed value with empty string, and returns NULL if it is equal. COALESCE() returns specified value or CURRENT_USER if the value is not set.

Comment: Thank very much. I come up with this: `CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `userlogtype_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `userlogtype` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.InsertDateTime IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.InsertDateTime = now(6);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.UpdateDateTime IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.UpdateDateTime = now(6);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.InsertUser IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.InsertUser = current_user();
    END IF;
    IF NEW.UpdateUser IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.UpdateUser = current_user();
    END IF;
END`

Comment: and `CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `userlogtype_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `userlogtype` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.UpdateDateTime = now(6);
        SET NEW.UpdateUser = current_user();
END`

Comment: but you solution is more elegant - ps. I added the code in the comment to help others too